# How to send array as req.body on node js source?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got a question.

I want to post some "array value" to "data.js".

which likes

```
router.post('/insertinfo', function(req,res,next){

    var gender = req.body.gender;
    var age = req.body.age;
    var data_no= req.params.data_no;
    var dataSub_no = req.body.dataSub_no;
```

But I don't know how to use array in req.body.dataSub_no..

Cause Array should be like this a[0],a[1],a[2].... etc.

How to get it? req.body.dataSub_no[0]? I don't think It's correct.

Here is "data.ejs"

The code is

```
<%
   var idxin=[];
 for(i=x; i<row.length; i++)
 {
    x=i;
    var oneItem = row[i];

    if(oneItem.dataSub_no==twoItem.dataSub_no)
    {   
%>

**<input type="radio" name="<%=oneItem.dataSub_no%>" id="<%=oneItem.dataChoice_no%>" value="<%=oneItem.dataChoice_no%>" ""><%=oneItem.dataChoice_content%><%=oneItem.dataSub_no%></input>**


    <%}
    if(oneItem.dataSub_no != twoItem.dataSub_no) break;
 }
    }
%>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Answer (score -1):

An object which points to an array can be send in body. Set the body type to `JSON(application/json)`.

```
{"data":["dummy1", "dummy2"]}
```

In node.js,

```
data_array = req.body.data;
// now data_array is an array and can be indexed as data_array[0] and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks But data value is random value.
So I can't put {"data":["dummy1", "dummy2"]} in json

Comment: From where do you get this data and how?

Comment: From <input type="radio" name="<%=oneItem.dataSub_no%>.......>

// dataSub_no is random value

then. 

var dataSub_no = req.body.dataSub_no[0]?? like this.